# Load again data when change bottom bar tab

Tags: android, fragment, bottomnavigationview

When i change tab of Bottom Bar for example when the home tab is selected and when i change the tab and select category tab in first time load data and it is not problem but when select again home tab again reload fragment and load data again.
how to resolve this problem and save state fragment.

My code:

```
bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
  @Override
  public void onTabSelected(int tabId) {
    displayFragment(tabId);
  }
});

private void displayFragment(int id) {
Fragment selectedFragment = null;
switch (id) {
  case R.id.tab_home:
    selectedFragment = HomeFragment.getInstance();
    break;

  case R.id.tab_category:
    selectedFragment = CategoryFragment.getInstace();
    break;
}
if (selectedFragment != null) {
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  transaction.replace(R.id.contentContainer, selectedFragment);
  transaction.commit();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can handle preserving and updating your fragments data throughout its life cycle. I would look into the lifecycle of activity fragments to better grasp what applies to your context. From 30k feet, after you call .replace() the fragment's override onCreateView() should fire, here you can handle your update logic.

As I mentioned, context is big here. If you end up changing your transaction logic, it could impact the life cycle of your fragments. For example, if you were hiding/showing your fragments, using the override onHidden() or onResume() could be a better solution.

In addition, you also should consider how your navigation logic impacts and interacts with your activity's/fragment's backstack. In your current logic, you're creating a new instance of the fragment each time a tab is selected.

Answer (score 0):

This is answer my question :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FeedFragment feedFragment;
PublishFragment publishFragment;
ServicesFragment servicesFragment;
SearchFragment searchFragment;
ProfileFragment profileFragment;

FragmentTransaction ft;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomBar bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
    feedFragment = new FeedFragment();
    publishFragment = new PublishFragment();
    servicesFragment = new ServicesFragment();
    searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
    profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();



    bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
            if (tabId == R.id.feed_icon) {
                GeneralUtils.logPrint("feed");
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                if (feedFragment.isAdded()) {
                    ft.show(feedFragment);
                } else {
                    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, feedFragment);
                }
                hideFragment(ft,publishFragment);
                hideFragment(ft, servicesFragment);
                hideFragment(ft,searchFragment);
                hideFragment(ft,profileFragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
            if (tabId == R.id.publish_icon) {
                GeneralUtils.logPrint("publish");
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                if (publishFragment.isAdded()) {
                    ft.show(publishFragment);
                } else {
                    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, publishFragment);
                }
                hideFragment(ft,feedFragment);
                hideFragment(ft, servicesFragment);
                hideFragment(ft,searchFragment);
                hideFragment(ft,profileFragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
            if (tabId == R.id.services_icon) {
                GeneralUtils.logPrint("services");
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                if (servicesFragment.isAdded()) {
                    ft.show(servicesFragment);
                } else {
                    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, servicesFragment);
                }
                hideFragment(ft,feedFragment);
                hideFragment(ft, publishFragment);
                hideFragment(ft,searchFragment);
                hideFragment(ft,profileFragment);
                ft.commit();

            }
            if (tabId == R.id.search_icon) {
                GeneralUtils.logPrint("search");
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                if (searchFragment.isAdded()) {
                    ft.show(searchFragment);
                } else {
                    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, searchFragment);
                }
                hideFragment(ft,feedFragment);
                hideFragment(ft,publishFragment);
                hideFragment(ft,servicesFragment);
                hideFragment(ft,profileFragment);
                ft.commit();

            }
            if (tabId == R.id.profile_icon) {
                GeneralUtils.logPrint("profile");
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                if (profileFragment.isAdded()) {
                    ft.show(profileFragment);
                } else {
                    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, profileFragment);
                }
                hideFragment(ft,feedFragment);
                hideFragment(ft, publishFragment);
                hideFragment(ft,servicesFragment);
                hideFragment(ft,searchFragment);
                ft.commit();

            }
        }
    });


}

private void hideFragment(FragmentTransaction ft, Fragment f) {
    if (f.isAdded()) {
        ft.hide(f);
    }
}
```

}